# Error when installing Twitter's BreakoutDetection package

Tags: r, macos

My system is MacBookPro, 10.8.5, RStudio Version 0.98.1049

When following directions to install Twitter's recently opensourced R package BreakoutDetection:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("twitter/BreakoutDetection")

library(BreakoutDetection)
```

I got the following error:

```
1 error generated.
make: *** [edm-multi.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘BreakoutDetection’
```

I did install Apple's Command Line Tools.

Comment: What is your R version? The compilation worked fine for me with R 3.1.1 on both 10.9 and 10.10. You should consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/twitter/BreakoutDetection/issues) on github for this. Also, how did you install the command-line tools?

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr. I am using R 3.1.1. I installed command-line tools for Mountain Lion via Apple developer website: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message. I hadn't updated my R version in a while, but installing the most recent version did the trick for me. I'm using Windows instead, not sure if that will make a difference here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jeff. I have latest R core and latest RStudio --- though for a Mac. Glad you got it running. Some initial feedback was to update my version of CLANG... really?